# How can I detect whether it is safe to use `in` operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This statement

```
 if ('foo' in bar)
```

throws a TypeError if `bar` is a string. I presume it's possible to have the same error for other types of object.

How can I tell if `bar` is an object which supports the `in` operator?

This code isn't sufficient: if `foo` is a string, it passes through to the `in` statement and throws.

```
if (foo instanceof Object && ! (foo instanceof String))
{
    if ('foo' in foo) {}
}
```

Comment: `typeof bar === 'object' && bar !== null` perhaps?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking when it is safe to use `in`. Your real question is about how you can tell if a variable is actually an object.

Comment: No, I want to know if I can use `in`. If it's not an object and I can use `in`, fine. Duck test.

Comment: Because 'foo' is not an instance of String. It's a string primitive, *instanceof* only works on Objects. Also, *instanceof* will not work across frames. Why not just use `typeof == 'object'`?

Comment: Only because I don't like using things I don't understand yet. Statements like "string primitives are not Strings" are the sort of thing that make me hesitate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`in` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) throws a TypeError is the right operand is not an object.

You can check if a value is an object using

```
Object(value) === value;
```

Additionally, `in` operator calls internal [[HasProperty]] method. [For ordinary objects it should never throw](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-hasproperty-p), but it might be the case in some exotic objects. For example,

```
var proxy = new Proxy({}, {has: () => {throw "Can't use `in`"}});
"property" in proxy; // Error: Can't use `in`
```

To handle these cases, I think you can only use a `try` statement, as [ringø suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36878454/1529630).

Comment: Apparently the right operand *is* an object. See the bottom of my question.

Comment: @spraff and how this also is not an answer actually?

Comment: Could you please clarify why this test would work but the test I tried doesn't?

Comment: @spraff That's strange, because OrdinaryHasInstance returns false for non objects, so your `foo instanceof Object` check should fail. Have you defined a custom @@hasInstance method? Or maybe `foo` is a proxy with a `has` trap which throws?

Comment: @spraff why do you think the one you tried would not work?

Comment: Okay, it seems that some filesystem quirks meant that the code changes weren't reaching the point of execution straight away, so there was some weird behaviour. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = {};

console.log(o.constructor === Object && o !== null); //true
```

Comment: @zzzzBov what is your point actually? you **can** use the `in` operator with both functoins and regular expressions.

Comment: This answer may throw (`o = null`), produce false positives (`String.prototype.constructor = Object; o = ""`) or false negatives (`o = []`).

Answer (score 0):

To catch any error

```
try { 
   if ('foo' in bar) { 
   }
}
catch(e) {
   // 'foo' is not in bar
}
```

or if you want just to *catch* errors for `'foo' in bar`

```
var inbar = false;
try { if ('foo' in bar) inbar = true; } 
catch(e) {}

if (inbar) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: That's an ex post facto solution. I want to anticipate and avoid the wrong code path. (Also, it mixes up code paths with *other* exceptions, which I may want to handle distinctly.)

Comment: Code edited to catch only errors due to `foo in bar`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I detect whether it is safe to use `in` operator in Javascript?

[From the ES5 spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.7)

> The production RelationalExpression : RelationalExpression in ShiftExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating RelationalExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. **If Type(rval) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.**
> 6. Return the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of rval with argument ToString(lval).

Emphasis mine.

In ES5 [`Type()`](http://es5.github.io/#Type) can be

- Undefined
- Null
- Boolean
- String
- Number
- Object

So to prevent `TypeError`s from happening, you have to make sure that it's *not*

- `undefined`
- `null`
- `true` or `false`
- any string value
- any number value

EcmaScript 2015 introduces the [`Symbol`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-symbol-type) type as well.

An example function might look like:

```
function canCallIn(arg) {
    if (arg === null ||
        arg === undefined)
        return false;
    switch (typeof arg) {
        case 'boolean':
        case 'string':
        case 'symbol':
        case 'number':
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Although you may be able to make various optimizations.

Comment: There are also ES6 symbols.

Comment: @Oriol, oh yea, i referenced the ES5 spec. I've updated my answer to make a note of it, but i'll have to go find an ES6 reference.